# Foundation 6 mediaquery on iphone

Tags: iphone, zurb-foundation, responsive, zurb-foundation-6

My test is very basic like this web page below. I don't understand why on iphone 6 or 5 Foundation seems not working. Do you have any idea ?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/foundation-sites@6.5.0-rc.2/dist/css/foundation.min.css" integrity="sha256-iJQ8dZac/jUYHxiEnZJsyVpKcdq2sQvdA7t02QFmp30= sha384-SplqNBo/0ZlvSdwrP/riIPDozO5ck8+yIm++KVqyMAC53S6m3BaV+2OLpi7ULOOh sha512-ho6hK4sAWdCeqopNZWNy1d9Ok2hzfTLQLcGSr8ZlRzDzh6tNHkVoqSl6wgLsqls3yazwiG9H9dBCtSfPuiLRCQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/foundation-sites@6.5.0-rc.2/dist/js/foundation.min.js" integrity="sha256-G6jsRyH1fxbsvFIXSCuwYmI1aIDYBa28xscrvmYjJy0= sha384-vtoG68NvPc9azmFJr447vvY8qgdyA4FdaJ5/bqvzIM4eAdZfO0iyRRF8l2AAscYI sha512-43seCcNrHA0BQgrtyajB9sp8yOdv5c8QdYvgjP7zJ7v+dmzAcxYDQ2gupb9aztsNWBq1COIp/3NHYkQs4l/dkg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
        <div class="cell">
            <div id="info"></div>
            <div id="info2"></div>
            <div id="info3"></div>
            <div id="info4"></div>
            <p class="show-for-small-only">You are <em>definitely</em> on a small screen.</p>
            <p class="show-for-medium-only">You are <em>definitely</em> on a medium screen.</p>
            <p class="show-for-large-only">You are <em>definitely</em> on a large screen.</p>
            <p class="show-for-landscape">You are in landscape orientation.</p>
            <p class="show-for-portrait">You are in portrait orientation.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).foundation();
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#info").html($( window ).width());
        $("#info2").html(JSON.stringify(Foundation.MediaQuery.queries));
        $("#info3").html(Foundation.MediaQuery.current);
        $("#info4").html(window.devicePixelRatio);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The result is medium any way flex grid or x-y grid.
I use sass for my project but for this test i use directly the full official cdn file. I still get same result.

Comment: I see that you have crossposted. Please link to the issue on GitHub and on GitHub to here.

Comment: I added an issue on GitHub https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/11482

Comment: User solved himself by using: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">` so I vote to close.